# Communication between two application( one in Qtc++ and another in C#)

Tags: c#, c++, communication

I have the need to do communicate two application, one in Qt c++ with another in C#.
The principle is the C# application launch the Qt application and the Qt return values to the C# application.
What is the best way for do that?

Gat

P.S: I'm beginner in C++ and intermediate in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options here.

If the returned value can fit in an integer, then you definitely should use the [`ExitCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx) of your Qt process.

If the returned value is more complex, then you have to write a more complicated IPC system (Inter Process Communication). There are several options too:

- write to a flat text file, and then read it in your C# application
- add a message to a queue (MSMQ for instance), then read it in your C# application
- host a webservice in the C# application, and call it from the Qt application (hosting a web service can easily be bone using WCF)
- use named pipe
- etc.

Comment: Thank you for this response.
My variable is effectively more complicated, i have already think about the flat text file but i have the need to be notify speedly afre each modification, so it's possible to know if the text file have been changed with an event?
Otherwise, it's possible to create Qt Dll and use this with my program C# ?

I'm not familiar with MSMQ but i will learn more about this and i believe web service is to much for  my application but it's a good idea

Comment: You can write some code to be notified (event-based) when a text file changes (in .Net: see `FileSystemWatcher`), but it's a quit slow/inefficient approach. And you would have to deal with concurrent read/write on a file, which might be tricky. MSMQ is a great approach (message-oriented approach), so you could have your Qt process that posts messages in a queue, and the C# process that dequeues messages when they are available in the queue (using a notification system, not polling). You should also be able to use a Qt dll in a C# program using P/Invoke.

Comment: yeah thank you for this solution, i haven't need a very good optimisation for this interaction and the FileSystemWatcher is the faster solution development for me. I will change this after when i will have more knowledge about MSMQ